# linux /tmp/ folder bad file

Tags: python-3.x, tmp

im writring a python script that checks some permmission and if you have permmission it will open xfreerdp.
Now i have a problem. If i just write in terminal the xfreerdp command it will open this. But if I use this python script it won't:
The error is that: /usr/bin/xfreerdp: /tmp/_MEI8cxde9/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)

But if i replace the libz.so.1 with /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 while running the python script it will work.

How can i tell what libz.so.1 copy in this /temp/ file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i tell what libz.so.1 copy in this /temp/ file?

You don't!

We need more debugging information, but there's clearly something very broken with your system setup. `.so` files should never be placed not even to think about loaded from `/tmp`. Doing so is a security nightmare, even if a "secure" randomized path component is used.

Comment: My system is "god". I created a new ubuntu desktop and this bug is still comes out. The python code is secured didn't write by my hand so i can't show you. But the software developer said he didn't create tmp files so i think python script create own tmp files and use wrong lib files